# Update slider ui value with button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out a way to update slider ui value not only on handle change but also on (plus/minus) button click. It does move the handle by one step on click, but not updating the value. Does anyone know where the problem is?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrx8rz79/12/)

```js
$(function () {
  var sizes = [ "0 years", "1 year", "2 years", "3 years", "4 years", "5 years", "6 years", "7 years" ];
  $("#slider-range-max3").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: sizes.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[0]);
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      $(".sup").text(sizes[ui.value]);
       var value = $(this).val(),
      button = $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      setTimeout(function () { /* update text after jQM refreshes slider */
        button.text(custom[value]);
    }, 0); }

  });

  $("#plus3").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value");
    var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value + step);
  });

  $("#minus3").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value")
    var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value - step);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click functions need to update the text and value of the slider

Add something like this

```
$("#sup").val(sizes[value+step]).text(sizes[value+step]);
```

as the last line of your click functions (obviously change the "+"s to "-"s depending on what the user clicked).

[JSfiddel here](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4eakah/)

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the issue. However, when value is the first from array and clicked 'minus' which adds one more step backwards, it becomes blank. Is it possible to define the first and  the last items in array so it won't move beyond that range?

Comment: wrap your click function actions in a check. Something like `if( (value - step) >= 0) {...` [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4eakah/13/)